# How to run through a lot of id's quickly?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to scrape a huge number of small web pages from a website. I already know what to do when I have the page, but to run through all of the pages (more than 5000), I found all of the individual page URLs were just like: `blablabla?id=1957-002A-02`.

I divided the URL into 4 sections: the first 4 digits (just a year fom 1957 to 2017), then after the hyphen 3 digits (just counting up) and a letter (same) and after another hyphen 2 digits (counting up).
What I know: there's a limit (let me explain):

`1957-002A-01` have some text I care about

`1957-002A-02` have some text I care about

`1957-002A-03` don't have any interesting text (I can detect it) and I can skip directly to:

`1957-002B-01` have some text I care about

`1957-002B-02` have some text I care about

`1957-002B-03` have some text I care about

`1957-002B-04` don't have any interesting text, I skip:

`1957-002C-01` don't have anything interesting, I skip:

`1957-002D-02` is the second in a row to now have anything, so I skip to the next letter:

`1957-003A-01`, and so on...

How can I roll through a lot of ID's while being able to skip at any moment?

Comment: If this is in a loop, just skip to the next iteration if you're not interested in that round.

Comment: `continue` is your friend

Comment: The OP has clearly mentioned he doesn't want to have to visit each URL to figure out whether it is important to him, he wants to skip to the next one which will be useful.

Comment: It looks like the choices made depend only on the last two digits of the page URLs. Is that correct, and if so what is their range of value (`00` to `99`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you'll have to write your own logic to jump to the next such id. Something to get you going:

```
years = [str(y) for y in range(1957, 1980)]
numbers = [str(k).rjust(3, "0") for k in range(1, 100)]
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
pages = [str(p).rjust(2, "0") for p in range(1, 20)]

params = [years, numbers, letters, pages]

def next_index(current):

    current = list(current)

    i = 3
    while i >= 0:
        current[i] = (current[i] + 1) % len(params[i])
        if current[i] == 0:
            i -= 1
        else:
            return current


def next_skip(indices, skip_level):

    indices = list(indices)

    # There are four parts to the id
    # skip level decides (from the left), which components to reset
    for i in range(skip_level + 1, 4):
        indices[i] = 0

    indices[skip_level] = (indices[skip_level] + 1) % len(params[skip_level])

    return indices

def make_element(indices):
    first = years[indices[0]]
    middle = numbers[indices[1]] + letters[indices[2]]
    last = pages[indices[3]]

    return "-".join([first, middle, last])

indices = [4, 4, 4, 5]
print(make_element(indices)) # 1961-005E-05 Original
print(make_element(next_index(indices))) # 1961-005E-06 Regular increment
print(make_element(next_skip(indices, 0))) # 1962-001A-00 (Increments year)
print(make_element(next_skip(indices, 1))) # 1961-006A-00 (Increments number)
print(make_element(next_skip(indices, 2))) # 1961-005F-00 (Increments letter)
```

What this basically does is counts in a custom base, then indexes elements according to the digits of that base. The `next_index` function does regular increments.

The `next_skip` function can take a parameter, which it will increment, and reset all lower components to zero, exactly the way you have posted in your question.

I'm afraid you'll have to write your own logic for deciding when to skip, and at what level.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Can you just tell me how to make the "pages" part start not at 00 but at 01?

Comment: @Julio974GamingJulio974Gaming Edited to make the pages start from 01. The next_skip and next_index functions are stateless, i.e. they do not change the input index array. Make sure that you are assigning the result of the next_skip or next_index functions back to the index array.

Comment: I tried and it works almost perfectly, i've edited the code just a bit, and I have a small problem...he is the code at the end: `    if 'Experiment Details: Error' in page:
        pagesSTREAK = pagesSTREAK+1
        if pagesSTREAK == 2:
            indices = next_skip(indices,2)
            lettersSTREAK = lettersSTREAK+1
            pagesSTREAK = 0
            if lettersSTREAK == 2:
                indices = next_skip(indices,1)
                numbersSTREAK = numbersSTREAK+1` (part 1)

Comment: (part 2:)`pagesSTREAK,lettersSTREAK = 0,0
                if numbersSTREAK == 2:
                    indices = next_skip(indices,0)
                    pagesSTREAK,lettersSTREAK,numbersSTREAK = 0,0,0
        print(pagesSTREAK,lettersSTREAK,numbersSTREAK)
        indices = next_index(indices)
        continue`

Answer (score 0):

here is a pseudocode:

```
def make_id():
    for year in range(1957, 2018):
        for num_1 in range(0, 999):
            for letter in ['a', 'b', ... , 'z']:
                for num_2 in range(0, 100):
                    yield "{}-{}-{}-{}".format(year, num_1, letter, num_2)

 for i in make_id():
    url = "blablabla?id={}".format(i)
    if valid(url):
        scrape(url)
```

you need to implement the `scrape` and `valid` functions.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. It's not about the validity of the URL, it is about the content. He wants to avoid scraping a series of URL's that he knows will not yield any results